# I am facing the routing error in rails as uninitialized constant UserController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, csv

I am going create a rail application which takes input from an csv file and show it on the webpage.

After doing all the needful stuffs I am facing this:
Routing Error 
uninitialized constant UserController

My app\controllers\users_controller.rb file is:-

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
    @users=User.all
   end

   def import
    User.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Activity data imported!"
   end
end
```

My  app\model\user.rb  file is:-
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      require 'csv'

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
        User.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

My app/views/users/index.html.erb file is:-

```
 <%= flash[:notice] %>

 <table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>

<tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= user.user %></td>
        <td><%= user.age %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>
<h4>Import the data!</h4>
<%= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My config\routes.rb file is:-

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'users/index'

get 'users/import'

resources :users do
 collection {post :import}
end
root to: "user#index"
end
```

I have not posted any #marked commented line from routes.rb file here.
The snapshot of the output screen is here:-
when clicking on the import csv button the following error is shown:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Rename `UsersController` to `UserController`

Comment: Change route line to `root to :"users#index"`

Comment: do  I need to change any file name?

Comment: I have changed this,,,but problem is not solved ,,displaying same error message! @LcLk

Comment: No.. Nothing else only  root to: "user#index" to root to: "users#index"

Comment: Don't change controller name .. only make change in root file as above suggested
(Controller name should be plural as rails default)

Comment: now its another error message

Comment: Unable to autoload constant UsersController, expected C:/Ruby21/rails/importcsv/app/controllers/users_controller.rb to define it @Mukesh

Comment: thnx mukesh,,,now its working fine..

Comment: but when I m clicking on the import csv button the following error message is shown:

Comment: unknown attribute 'User' for User.

Comment: in `index.html.erb` file change  `user.user`  to `user.name`? ( i am guessing)

Comment: no the attribute in the excel file is User

Comment: Now I am facing another problem. If there is any quoted string in the csv file the program is unable to parse it.So what changes should I made in the user.rb file to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

You just have a mismatch in the pluralization of UsersController vs UserController. The convention in Rails is to use plural for controller names.

Change the line in your routes.rb file to:

```
root to: "users#index"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  controller file from app\controllers\users_controller.rb to app\controllers\user_controller.rb

Comment: Bro, we should not go against rails default convention  :)

Comment: Rails = Convention over configuration. It's a little devilish thing to do it other way

Comment: @Mukesh and Ruben Barbosa : My Bad

Answer (score 0):

As per the error the problem is Routing error so check the route.rb file and as per the above answers you need to change the line

```
root to: "user#index"
```

to

```
root to: "users#index"
```

in the  config\routes.rb file.

Comment: Great.. Good luck ahead